# Using bash for loop to acquire the file content which the file is written in another text file

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to acquire the file content which the file is written in another text file

My program is :

```
for i in $(cat FILE)
do
    echo $i
done
```

I hope the result will be

```
OBJECT1
OBJECT2
LINE1
LINE2
```

but the result is only

```
aa
bb
```

which the program doesn't read the content of **aa** and **bb**

The file name and the content are listed below:

FILE:

```
aa
bb
```

aa:

```
OBJECT1
OBJECT2
```

bb:

```
LINE1
LINE2
```

Comment: Replace `echo $i` with `cat "$i"`

Comment: It is not good to loop through `$(cat FILE)` with a [for](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)  loop. Use a [while loop](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I think you are trying to do.

Given:

```
$ cat FILE
aa
bb
$ cat aa
OBJECT1
OBJECT2
$ cat bb
LINE1
LINE2
```

You can do:

```
$ while IFS= read -r fn || [[ -n $fn ]]; do cat "$fn"; done <FILE
OBJECT1
OBJECT2
LINE1
LINE2
```

---

Explanation:

1. `<FILE` read the file `FILE` and redirect the contents to the while loop
2. `while IFS= read -r fn; do ... done` Defines a [while loop](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). Read the file for each line terminated by a CR into `fn`. The `IFS=` [prevents the trimming](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001#Trimming) of leading and trailing whitespace. The `-r` option prevents backslash interpretation.
3. `|| [[ -n $fn ]]` returns true for the loop to continue if the last line of the file `FILE` is not terminated with a `\n`. If you *know* that your file has that termination, you do not need this part.
4. `cat "$fn"` runs the program `cat` with the quoted file name `"$fn". It needs to be quoted to keep the file name intact if there are names such as "big file.txt"

Comment: The `|| [[ ... ]]` part is cruft to deal with broken files. It shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @chepner: Appreciate the fact, will rem it!

Comment: @chepner: `|| [[ ... ]]` deals with a file that is not properly terminated with a `\n` on the last line. That happens to *me* fairly regularly. Enough so that I just use that part as a default in my Bash while loops. I added an explanation...

Comment: @chepner: Consider if the source of `FILE` was `printf "aa\nbb" >FILE` No terminating `\n` in `FILE` and `while read -r fn ; do echo "$fn"; done <FILE` would only echo `aa` Habit for me I suppose.

Comment: That isn't valid text file according to POSIX; *every* line is supposed to end with a newline.

Comment: Agreed, but I cannot call the POSIX police on the ding dang people who give me those files!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`while read LINE; do
  cat "$LINE"
done <FILE`

should work just fine. All the `$(cat)` versions use a subshell which executes an external command (`cat`) which is at least not optimal. The above uses pure bash to loop over each line of FILE and `cat`s the file read.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
    for i in $(cat FILE)
do
for e in $(cat "$i")
do
    echo "$e"
done
done
```

I think this is what you want.

Comment: 1) What if one of the lines of file is `*`? 2) Quote your variables or there will be word splitting and parameter expansion 3) Use a [while loop](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) to read a file, not a [for loop](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) 4) Check your Bash scripts with [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net)